# Ruby: Extract data from nested arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I get in Ruby from a nested array like this

```
[["21:45",8.0],["11:20",14.5],["15:30",21.0]]
```

get a result like this (each subarray in a single line):

```
[
  "21:45 o'clock 08.0 °C",
  "11:20 o'clock 14.5 °C",
  "15:30 o'clock 21.0 °C"
]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) or simple interpolation.

Comment: `.map{|n| "#{n[0]} o'clock #{"%01d" % n[1]} °C"}`

Answer (score 5):

The key here is [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) which makes it easy to convert in conjunction with `map` since your incoming data is already in a concise form:

```
list.map do |row|
  "%s o'clock %04.1f °C" % row
end
```

This helps with the formatting of `8.0` to `08.0` as well using the `%04.1f` placeholder.